# Stuck on Download Pending in Play Store after Updating to Lollipop

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop

Good day, as the title states, whenever I download an app from the Play Store, it just says Download Pending.

There is no queued apps being downloaded. I tried the force stop, clear cache, clear data and uninstall updates of Play store and Download Manager, restarted the phone, but still no luck.

One thing I notice is that when I revert it to the factory version, I managed to download an app, but when I tried to download another, it just says Error 907. When I opened the Play Store, it's the latest version again.

I think its in the version, but I'm hoping for other fixes to this

Phone - Cherry Mobile Flare S3

OS - Lollipop

Google Play Store Version - 7.3.07.K-all [0] [PR] 139935798

Comment: Have you checked clearing cache of  google play services

Comment: @RahulGopi It worked like a charm!! Thank you very much, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. No forum seemed to have suggested clearing the cache of the google play services, just the google services framework

Comment: I'm on A-12. This worked with some effort - effort because I'm new to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the Play Store data following these instructions.

1. From the **Settings** app, choose **Apps**.
2. Choose **Google Play Store** from the list of apps. A new screen will appear.
3. Click **Force Stop**.
4. Click **Storage** and then **Clear data**.
5. At the top right, click the three dots, then Click **Uninstall updates** to revert to the original version of Play Store that came with the phone.

Follow the same instructions again for the **Google Play Services** app, but this time use **Clear cache** instead of **Clear data**.

Comment: This fix no longer seems sufficient to resolve this problem.  I followed these steps and I get stuck at "Downloading..." now instead of download pending.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to fix this issue:

“Navigate your device Settings menu, then go to Play Store. On Play Store page select Clear Cache and Clear Data functions. In doing so, you will delete only Play Store info data. Hence you should not worry about losing important files. If you use Marshmallow or later Android versions, select "Storage", and then clear cache and data from that page. “

Source: https://android-fix.com/google-play-problems/50-download-pending.html﻿